# Cucumber Report Missing report result - report was not successfully completed

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, jenkins-pipeline, cucumber-jvm

I use Cucumber Reports plugin to get cucumber reports in pipeline jobs it works fine before but now i have this error:

```
[CucumberReport] Preparing Cucumber Reports
[CucumberReport] JSON report directory is "target/"
[CucumberReport] Copied 1 json files from workspace "c:/jenkins/workspace/..." to reports directory "/var/jenkins_home/jobs/..."
[CucumberReport] Copied 0 properties files from workspace "c:/jenkins/workspace/..." to reports directory "/var/jenkins_home/jobs/..."
[CucumberReport] Processing 1 json files:
[CucumberReport] /var/jenkins_home/jobs/.../cucumber.json
[CucumberReport] Missing report result - report was not successfully completed
[CucumberReport] Build status is left unchanged
```

And if i run only some features the reports generate without any issue, i have this issue only if i run all features

for information i have about 15 feature with +2000 steps

Comment: Please delete files or cucumber reports before generating new reports.   Are you using pretty format ?

Comment: @BostonStar yes here is my class runner `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/java/features", glue = {"steps"}, plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber.json"})
public class RunFeaturesTest {}`

Comment: I tried to delete cucumber reports before running my tests, but i have the same issue

Comment: Please make sure you have right path because that can also cause this error. please remember every runner file should have unique json name that should be base on feature file name otherwise it overwrite value

Answer (score 0):

**It can be for several reasons.**

1. verify your pipeline, in the jenkinsfile, it is necessary when using the Cucumber Options indicate the path of the features

```
  stage 'Run Test'
         script 
            {sh "mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options=\"src/test/resources/features/ --tags @YourTagName\""}
```

2. Verify plugin to use cucumber report in your JenkinsFile always put that inside "Finally"

```
      finally {
                           cucumber buildStatus: "UNSTABLE", 
                           fileIncludePattern: "**/cucumber.json",
                           jsonReportDirectory: 'target'
                            }
```

Example RunTest.java

```
package runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "pretty", "json:target/cucumber.json" }, features = {
        "src/test/resources/features/" }, glue = { "classpath:" }, tags = { "@YourTagName" })
public class RunTest {

}
```