# Missing report result - report was not successfully completed with CucumberReport

Tags: jenkins, gradle, cucumber, report, cucumber-jvm

There is a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48640543/cucumber-report-missing-report-result-report-was-not-successfully-completed) but with no answers and no progress in solving it.

I am running Selenium tests with Cucumber and with Gradle as the build tool. In Jenkins.

This is my `build.gradle` file:

```
task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast{
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'stepmethods', 'src/main/java/features', '--tags', 'not @proba and not @test and not @rucno and not @nedovrseno']

        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to exclude some scenarios from the feature I am testing so I added the `'--tags', 'not @proba and not @test and not @rucno and not @nedovrseno'` part to Gradle task arguments.

After that (and I'm not 100% sure this is the cause) tests run fine in a Jenkins job, but the reports with [Cucumber reports plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/cucumber-reports-plugin) are not getting generated.

Instead, this is the Jenkins console output:

```
15:09:02 BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 58s
15:09:02 3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
15:09:02 Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to SUCCESS
15:09:02 [CucumberReport] Using Cucumber Reports version 4.6.0
15:09:02 [CucumberReport] JSON report directory is ""
15:09:02 [CucumberReport] Copied 1 json files from workspace "C:\Users\me\.jenkins\workspace\Project Name" to reports directory "C:\Users\me\.jenkins\jobs\Project Name\builds\12\cucumber-html-reports\.cache"
15:09:02 [CucumberReport] Copied 4 properties files from workspace "C:\Users\me\.jenkins\workspace\Project Name" to reports directory "C:\Users\me\.jenkins\jobs\Project Name\builds\12\cucumber-html-reports\.cache"
15:09:02 [CucumberReport] Processing 1 json files:
15:09:02 [CucumberReport] C:\Users\me\.jenkins\jobs\Project Name\builds\12\cucumber-html-reports\.cache\report.json
15:09:02 [CucumberReport] Missing report result - report was not successfully completed
15:09:02 [CucumberReport] Build status is left unchanged
15:09:02 Finished: SUCCESS
```

So, the files are processed, but the report is missing. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Added second '--plugin' to string to account for the OP's finding.

Removed additional examples.

---

Try

```
task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast{
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--plugin', 'html:some/dir', '--glue', 'stepmethods', 'src/main/java/features', '--tags', 'not @proba and not @test and not @rucno and not @nedovrseno']

        }
    }
}
```

You didn't specify which report you wanted nor where you wanted it generated.  This gives you pretty and html.

Comment: I'm getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported scheme: html:report
 at cucumber.runtime.io.MultiLoader.resources(MultiLoader.java:25)
 at cucumber.runtime.model.FeatureLoader.loadFromFeaturePath(FeatureLoader.java:42)
 at cucumber.runtime.model.FeatureLoader.load(FeatureLoader.java:36)
 at cucumber.runtime.model.FeatureLoader.load(FeatureLoader.java:22)
 at cucumber.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.get(FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.java:23)...
`

Comment: Please update your question with the current content of task cucumber().

Comment: I was able to get it working, but I needed to preface 'json:report.json' with '--plugin', like this: `args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--plugin', 'json:report.json', '--glue', 'stepmethods', 'src/main/java/features', '--tags', 'not @proba and not @test and not @rucno and not @nedovrseno']`

Comment: That makes sense.  "The --plugin option can specify a class that implements one or more of gherkin.formatter.Formatter,gherkin.formatter.Reporter,cucumber.api.StepDefinitionReporter".  I wonder if what you need is '--plugin', 'pretty, html:some/dir', ...